# Clustering of variables

Tags: machine-learning

I have applied some clustering methods (k-means) to regroup instances (examples) into categories. 
I am facing a dimensionality reduction problem in which I have few instances (100) and many variables (10 million). I think some of these variables have a “similar behavior” and I want to regroup them. Is it possible to do clustering on the variables? If no, why not?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by similar behavior?

Comment: Maybe you could just check if there variables alter the clusters. If you remove some variables and the result is the same, maybe you can use this variable subset

Comment: @Leo I mean I think the variables are correlated. They often take zero values for the same instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean there may be correlation in the varialbes(feature), so there should be some method to reduce the feature dimension . usually feature dimension is not doing by regroup  , [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or SVD is applied .

Comment: So clustering the variables would not work you think?

Comment: @bigTree you can have a try , it might be a problem to choose the parameter K ,and it may not converge, it is convenient to do this with PCA, the eigenvalue respect to the new feature represents the importance of the new feature, so it is convenient to choose the number of dimensions (PCA is usually a good choice when the distribution of the data is joint normal)